# change column value and change its column type

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this kind of dataset called df

this is part of the dataset that i want to change

```
SaleCondition    SalePrice
<chr>            <chr>
Normal           $208500
Normal           $181500
Normal           $223500
Abnorml          $140000
Normal           $250000
Normal           $143000
```

I know how to change column `SalePrice` to numeric type with this code

```
df$SalePrice = as.numeric(df$SalePrice)
```

But I dont know how delete all of the `$` character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` for 'find and replace' and then convert to numeric

```
df$SalePrice <- as.numeric(sub("\\$", "", df$SalePrice))
```

Another alternative is `parse_number` from readr package

```
library(readr)
df$SalePrice <- parse_number(df$SalePrice)
```